# Script error copying to Rackspace

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, rackspace, rackspace-cloud, timeoutexception

I am using Rackspace for Ubuntu cloud server. Everyday a script(I guess the script is from rackspace) executes on the cloud servers which copies the backfile to the Rackspace CloudFiles and sends the mail as if the files are copied and I've scheduled the script on the cloud servers. I've no much knowledge of the script and I guess the script is based on Cruise(as I could see build.xml, some jar files ...). Everyday the files are copied to the Rackspace from cloud servers but sometimes don't know why, the files will be copied to Rackspace sending an error failure message or sometimes the files will not be copied and sends the error failure message like the one below.

```
Error while backing up on Station1 on 03/03/2011 04:50 AM and reason for error is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Anybody using Rackspace?, anybody has any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I never seen this error to be honest and this should not happen. If you are copying from cloudservers to cloudfiles I would advise to use servicenet network. IE: something like that for PHP and Python :

http://blog.chmouel.com/2009/10/14/how-to-connect-to-rackspace-cloud-files-via-servicenet/

Comment: Wow!. I thought no one going to answer this you came up with some idea. I'll try this. Thanks!